# Couldn't Install Microsoft.Nuget.VisualStudio.Core ReturnCode 1603

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, nuget

I've been having some trouble with the latest version of the vs2017 Community Installer installing Visual Studio.

```
Package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.NuGet.Core,version=15.0.40902.5706' failed to install.
    Search URL
        https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Microsoft.VisualStudio.NuGet.Core;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=1603
    Details
        Return code: 1603
        Return code details: Fatal error during installation.
    Log
        C:\Users\myuseraccount\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20190110143209_001_Microsoft.VisualStudio.NuGet.Core.log
    Impacted workloads
        .NET Core cross-platform development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreTools,version=15.8.27906.1)
        .NET desktop development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop,version=15.8.27906.1)
        ASP.NET and web development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb,version=15.8.27906.1)
        Azure development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Azure,version=15.8.27906.1)
        Data storage and processing (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Data,version=15.6.27309.0)
        Desktop development with C++ (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop,version=15.9.28307.102)
        Game development with Unity (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedGame,version=15.0.27005.2)
        Mobile development with .NET (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat,version=15.9.28107.0)
        Mobile development with JavaScript (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.WebCrossPlat,version=15.7.27625.0)
        Node.js development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Node,version=15.9.28107.0)
        Office/SharePoint development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Office,version=15.8.27924.0)
        Universal Windows Platform development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal,version=15.9.28307.102)
    Impacted components
        .NET Core 2.0 development tools (Microsoft.NetCore.ComponentGroup.DevelopmentTools,version=15.8.27729.1)
        .NET Core 2.1 development tools (Microsoft.NetCore.ComponentGroup.DevelopmentTools.2.1,version=15.8.27924.0)
        .NET Core 2.1 development tools (Microsoft.NetCore.ComponentGroup.Web.2.1,version=15.8.27924.0)
        .NET desktop development tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Prerequisites,version=15.7.27625.0)
        ASP.NET and web development tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Web,version=15.8.27825.0)
        ASP.NET and web development tools prerequisites (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Web,version=15.9.28219.51)
        Azure Cloud Services core tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.Waverton,version=15.9.28107.0)
        Azure Cloud Services tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Azure.CloudServices,version=15.0.26504.0)
        Azure Data Lake and Stream Analytics Tools (Microsoft.Component.Azure.DataLake.Tools,version=15.9.28107.0)
        Azure development prerequisites (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Azure.Prerequisites,version=15.9.28107.0)
        Azure Resource Manager core tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.ResourceManager.Tools,version=15.9.28107.0)
        Azure Resource Manager tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Azure.ResourceManager.Tools,version=15.0.27005.2)
        Cloud tools for web development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Web.CloudTools,version=15.8.27729.1)
        Data sources for SQL Server support (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.DataSources,version=15.0.26621.2)
        Developer Analytics tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.AppInsights.Tools,version=15.8.27825.0)
        F# language support (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.FSharp,version=15.8.27825.0)
        F# language support for web projects (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.FSharp.WebTemplates,version=15.8.27705.0)
        Managed Desktop Workload Core (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Core,version=15.8.27729.1)
        Microsoft Azure WebJobs Tools (Component.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.AzureFunctions,version=15.7.27617.1)
        Microsoft Azure WebJobs Tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.AzureFunctions,version=15.7.27617.1)
        Mobile development with JavaScript core features (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Cordova,version=15.0.26606.0)
        Node.js development support (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Node.Tools,version=15.8.27825.0)
        NuGet package manager (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.NuGet,version=15.9.28016.0)
        Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Sharepoint.Tools,version=15.8.27924.0)
        Redgate SQL Search (Component.Redgate.SQLSearch.VSExtension,version=3.1.7.2062)
        SQL Server Data Tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.SSDT,version=15.9.28107.0)
        Test Adapter for Google Test (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.TestAdapterForGoogleTest,version=15.8.27906.1)
        Testing tools core features (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TestTools.Core,version=15.7.27520.0)
        Universal Windows Platform tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.UWP.Support,version=15.9.28119.51)
        Universal Windows Platform tools for Cordova (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Cordova,version=15.9.28307.102)
        Universal Windows Platform tools for Xamarin (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Xamarin,version=15.9.28307.102)
        Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO) (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TeamOffice,version=15.7.27625.0)
        Visual Studio Tools for Unity (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Unity,version=15.7.27617.1)
        Windows Communication Foundation (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Wcf.Tooling,version=15.8.27924.0)
        Windows Workflow Foundation (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Workflow,version=15.8.27825.0)
        Xamarin (Component.Xamarin,version=15.8.27906.1)
```

I'm not really sure why this is happening.  I've tried doing a clean install of Windows - didn't work; I've tried going to the URL [here from MSFT](https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Microsoft.VisualStudio.NuGet.Core;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=1603) and I get 0 results from the search.

The end result on opening VS is that Visual Studio has little to no tooling available for creating new ASP.NET projects, C# desktop projects, etc.

Here is the log file dump:

```
[19ac:0030][2019-01-10T14:36:03] Opening the package for processing
[19ac:0030][2019-01-10T14:36:03] Using package payload to get the embedded manifest
[19ac:0030][2019-01-10T14:36:03] Error 0x80131509: Error processing vsix manifest: System.InvalidOperationException: Specified part does not exist in the package.
   at System.IO.Packaging.Package.GetPart(Uri partUri)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Installer.VsixInstaller.GetEmbeddedVsixPackageFromPayload(Package package, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Installer.VsixInstaller.GetEmbeddedVsixPackage(IPackageIdentity vsix, Package package, ExecuteAction action, ILogger logger, Boolean isManifestCached)
   at System.IO.Packaging.Package.GetPart(Uri partUri)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Installer.VsixInstaller.GetEmbeddedVsixPackageFromPayload(Package package, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Installer.VsixInstaller.GetEmbeddedVsixPackage(IPackageIdentity vsix, Package package, ExecuteAction action, ILogger logger, Boolean isManifestCached)
```

[image: Installer Error]

[image: missing tooling error]

Comment: Does the log file in the error message provide any additional information?

Comment: Basically that it couldn't install the NuGet extension (VSIX).  I'll append to my original post.

Comment: If you're still having the problem , then I suggest you use ["report a problem"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio-2017?view=vs-2017).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @zivkan, I think I might.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR;** Visual Studio creates a Packages folder under your hidden ***C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio*** directory.  After reviewing the error logs, I discovered that the package for NuGet somehow got corrupted.  Try deleting your packages folder and seeing if that clears up your installation; otherwise, just follow everything above.

---

After a lot of time working on this, here's what actually fixed the problem.

1. C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio - Delete the Packages folder here.
2. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio - Delete the folders 2017, Installer, and Shared.  Basically everything underneath the VS 2017 Install directory.
3. Re-run the installer for VS 2017.
4. NuGet.Core should be installed this time.

I installed my Visual Studio from a Layout (offline installation)- details on how to do that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2017).  I would recommend creating a layout file (basically an ISO) so that you don't run into issues like I did above.

**--For issues with the the current preview version**

I was also getting errors with the Visual Studio 2019 preview version.  What I did to fix that was create a layout (offline installer) of the 2019 version and deleted the package that was breaking my installation from my ProgramData subdirectory (C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio). I then ran the installer with the option --noWeb and it worked.  Thanks Microsoft for giving us the ability to create layouts!!!!

Answer (score 0):

> Couldn't Install Microsoft.Nuget.VisualStudio.Core ReturnCode 1603

According to the error log, the issue should be that Visual Studio does not properly install the NuGet extension package. To resolve this issue, you should open the installer to reinstall the NuGet extension.

- Modify the installer.
- Switch to Individual components.
- Under the code tools, uncheck the NuGet package manager.
- Close the Installer, then re-open it, recheck the NuGet package manager.

[image]

If it not helps, or you can not modify the installer, please try to **repair or re-install** the Visual Studio to resolve this issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'll give this a shot. Thanks @Leo

Comment: I understand that NuGet is included part of dotnet cli and VS 2017.  Is it possible to load the extension manually by including the necessary files outside of the visual studio installer, by, say, moving them to the NuGet folder in the vs install directory under packages?

Comment: @cloudstrifebro, Just as you said, NuGet is included part of VS 2017. So it seems we could not load the extension manually. Using installer to reinstall this part of extension should be a effective method.

Comment: That didn't work for me either...I'm going to try and use a vs install layout instead and see if that fixes it by running my custom layout with the --noWeb switch.

Comment: I ended up just copying an older 2017 VS installation from another machine that was good to fix this problem.  I'll provide an answer once I determine specifically what was wrong (if I can) ;)  Thanks for the suggestions @Leo.  It might just be my machine.  Are you aware if there's a problem with the 2017 Community installer at the moment, or if anyone on your team is able to reproduce the above?